# CSS flex item's main-axis alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm very new to CSS, and I'm struggling on positioning a flex item (DownloadButton) the way I want it too.

I want to position a flex item a certain way, but my googling skills are failing me.

The current state looks like this:

`Icon    DownloadButton    DeleteButton`

What I want is this:

`Icon       DownloadButton DeleteButton`

I thought I could use `align-items`, but that's for the cross axis. Rather than even spacing, like the normal flex behavior, I want my DownloadButton hugging the DeleteButton at the end. However, my Googling skills have failed me. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 3):

I would align the items to the end (for preference) and then adjust the first one.

*As pointed out in the comments the end alignment is not necessary as the effect is caused by the margin adjustment.*

```css
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: .5em;
}
button:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Icon</button>
  <button>Download</button>
  <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The alignment is done by the auto margin. `justify-content: flex-end` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles to the container:

```
#flex-container { /*Select Your Flex Container*/
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Add these styles for the flexible items:

```
.flexible-items { /*Select The Children Of The Flex Container*/
flex-grow: 0; /*This Is Default*/
}
#Icon {
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If you want some space between the other two flexible items, you can achieve this by multiple methods, 1 being to add some margin and padding styles for their sides.